# Error building a java app in Azure devOps

Tags: java, maven, ant, azure-devops, continuous-integration

While implementing CI pipeline in VSTS(Azure DevOps) for building a java application i get the below error.
[image]

The tasks i have used in this are..
[image: Tasks]

Its a java based project, but not mavenised. It does not have pom.xml
I am using Ant task/agent in the pipeline.

Comment: You can set the value of variable  "system.debug" as true. In this way, you can get more detailed logs. Put the logs in your description, so other can have a better understanding of your issue.

Comment: What did you configure in the build task?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Question updated.

Comment: @Salman Can you expand the error?